# Rounding Issue Continues in CE 1.8

Tags: price, magento-1.8, tax

I am posting this as I am still having rounding issues with 1.8 and I want to see am I the only one.

When adding 1 product (£108.33 excl tax/£130 incl tax), it works but if I increase the qty to 2 I get incorrect calculations (£259.99 incl tax). I am stumped as I thought this was fixed in 1.8.

**My Cart**

[image: Shopping Cart with incorrect Calculations in CE 1.8]

**These are my tax calculation settings:**

[image: Tax Calculations CE 1.8]

I hope you can help.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Do you need to make tax calculate based on unit price rather than row total?

Comment: @AdamMoss I tried Unit Price but no joy.

Comment: Does nothing change when you set it to Unit Price? Unit price should make the calculation round(108.33 * 1.2,2) * 2  , but row price like your showing would do (108.33 * 2) * 1.2

Comment: Is this 1.8 or 1.8.1?

Comment: Sweet, nice to know it marches on and on and on... Oops, sarcasm detected, ducking the cream pie...

Comment: Fabian Blechschmidt, I am using 1.8. Richard, No nothing changed for me when using Unit Price.

Answer (score 1):

There were a large number of additional tax calculation updates rolled out in Community Edition 1.8.1.0.

> **Tax Calculation Updates:** Building on tax improvements made in our most recent release, Magento Community Edition 1.8.1.0 provides more accurate and consistent Value Added Tax (VAT) and Fixed Product Tax (FPT) calculations for the Magento admin, invoices, and credit memos. It also improves tax calculations for cross-border transactions, bundled products, and multi-tax scenarios, as well as supports the Waste Electrical and Electronic Equipment recycling tax in the EU. — [Source Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/magento-community-edition-1810-is-here/)

For further details on these, head over to the [release notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes?icid=BLOG_magentoce1810release_getstartedreleasenotes#tax-11310) page. My recommendation would be to upgrade to CE 1.8.1 and see if your luck changes. If not, post back here and describe with very precise details how you're products are setup and how someone can reproduce this in a completely blank CE 1.8.1.0 installation; this way someone can attempt to reproduce and/or patch it.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by setting the prices Including tax in the admin.